# Where to store an array of object, which is part of an another object in angular2?

Tags: arrays, angular, object, angular5

I have a companies' object. In this object, I have some other object..

```
object{
 country {
         country_code: string;
         country_name: string
 }, 
 yearlyIncome {
         id: number;
         amount: string;
 }, 
 ...
}
```

In my project you can create new companies, or edit an existing one. I use this objects there in dropdown lists. So you not writing this datas in to a textfield, you select countries in the dropdown list, select yearly income category, like 0-1000 USD, 1000-5000 USD, ... .
So this objects have default datas, but I don't know where to store this datas. I don't thinks this is good idea to store this datas in a database, bacause, this datas will not change. So I want to write the dafault datas to the code. But where to? Create a model and a service for each object? But if I do, there will be a lot of models and services. Store it in the company service? But then the company service will be very long.
How should I solve this problem?

Comment: So you want to store the dropdown data somewhere? I would store them in the database and have a service bring them down in your constructor.

Comment: Also, If possible I would create an Admin Page that will allow you to edit the dropdown values. This way you don't have to access the database to edit them when they change. Because they will change.

Answer (score 2):

Store the default values in a database and use the service to get the values :

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.countries$ = this.companyService.getDefaultCountries();
    this.incomeRanges$ = this.companyService.getDefaultIncomeRanges();
}
```

Make sure that your backend caches these values.
If you are using Express.js, you could use [apicache](https://github.com/kwhitley/apicache)

Then in your template, you can use this to initialize your dropdowns

```
<select>
        <option *ngFor="let country of countries$ | async" value="country">{{country.name}}</option>
</select>
```